# Cómo guardar la mejor puntuación en un juego

Tags: android

Estoy creando un juego sencillo que cuenta las pulsaciones del jugador a un botón en un tiempo determinado. El problema está en que no logro enlazar bien la función `getSharedPreferences` para que guarde la puntuación más alta, siempre se queda a 0.

Aquí está el código en java:

```
public class player110s extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageButton;
    private TextView contador;
    private int cont = 0;
    private int high = 0;
    private TextView cuenta10s;
    private TextView highest10;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player110s);
        final int high = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("cont", 0);
        finaljuego();

        cuenta10s=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cuentap1);
        contador=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador);
        highest10=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.highest10);

        imageButton=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cont++;
                contador.setText(" " + cont);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public void finaljuego()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 950)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                cuenta10s.setText("00:" + (millisUntilFinished/950));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (cont > high)
                    getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("cont", cont).commit();

                Intent nuevoform=new Intent(player110s.this, fin110s.class);
                nuevoform.putExtra("contador", contador.getText()+"");
                nuevoform.putExtra("highest10", highest10.getText()+"");
                startActivity(nuevoform);
                finish();

            }

        }.start();
    }

}
```

**¿Hay alguna manera para que la puntuación obtenida se guarde correctamente?**

Comment: podrías probar si obtienes "true" dentro de tu método onFinish():    boolean seGuardo = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("cont", cont).commit();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu lectura y salvado de la preferencia es correcta ya que usas el mismo nombre de preferencia `"myPrefs"`. El error radica en que declaras la variable `high` como `final int` por lo cual no esta cambiando el valor:

```
final int high = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("cont", 0);
```

Lo correcto sería :

```
high = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("cont", 0);
```

ya que tienes declarada la variable `high` a nivel de clase:

```
 private int high = 0;
```

También recuerda que al iniciar tu aplicación cont = 0, por lo tanto no es mayor que high y no puede guardar el valor:

```
if (cont > high)
       editor.putInt("cont", cont).commit();
```

El valor de `cont` únicamente aumenta cuando das click al boton:

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cont++;
                contador.setText(" " + cont);
            }

        });
```

Comment: Sigue sin funcionar. Lo que hace es guardar el contador en el textView de la puntuación más alta, pero en el último segundo. Después, al iniciar de nuevo la Activity, se reinicia. Está bien el enlace de los conts?

Comment: Ya vi cual es el problema real, he actualizado mi respuesta, cont++ únicamente va a aumentar cuando des click en el imageButton, si no das click siempre se conservaría con valor de 0 y no podra ejecutarse la actualización del valor de la preferencia "cont" (editor.putInt("cont", cont).commit();).

Comment: Funciona, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Probablemente es porque tu `SharedPreferences` y tu `Editor` están en diferentes instancias. Prueba instanciándolos una sola vez. Te dejo el código con mi sugerencia implementada:

```
public class player110s extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView imageButton;
    private TextView contador;
    private int cont = 0;
    private int high = 0;
    private TextView cuenta10s;
    private TextView highest10;

    private SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player110s);

        sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs",MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        final int high = sharedPreferences.getInt("cont", 0);
        finaljuego();

        cuenta10s=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.cuentap1);
        contador=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.contador);
        highest10=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.highest10);

        imageButton=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageButton10);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cont++;
                contador.setText(" " + cont);
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
    }

    public void finaljuego()
    {
        new CountDownTimer(10000, 950)
        {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                cuenta10s.setText("00:" + (millisUntilFinished/950));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {
                if (cont > high)
                    editor.putInt("cont", cont).commit();

                Intent nuevoform=new Intent(player110s.this, fin110s.class);
                nuevoform.putExtra("contador", contador.getText()+"");
                nuevoform.putExtra("highest10", highest10.getText()+"");
                startActivity(nuevoform);
                finish();

            }

        }.start();
    }
}
```